# spark throws error when reading hive transaction table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

i am trying to do select * from db.abc in hive,this hive table was loaded using spark

it does not work shows an error:

> Error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   bucketId out of range: -1 (state=,code=0)

when i use the following properties i was able to query for hive:

```
set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.optimize.ppd=true;
set hive.optimize.index.filter=true;
set hive.tez.bucket.pruning=true;
set hive.explain.user=false; 
set hive.fetch.task.conversion=none;
```

now when i try to read the same hive table db.abc using spark , i am recieving the error as below:

> Clients can access this table only if they have the following
>   capabilities:
>   CONNECTORREAD,HIVEFULLACIDREAD,HIVEFULLACIDWRITE,HIVEMANAGESTATS,HIVECACHEINVALIDATE,CONNECTORWRITE.
>   This table may be a Hive-managed ACID table, or require some other
>   capability that Spark currently does not implement;   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.CatalogUtils$.throwIfNoAccess(ExternalCatalogUtils.scala:280)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveTranslationLayerCheck$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(HiveTranslationLayerStrategies.scala:105)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveTranslationLayerCheck$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(HiveTranslationLayerStrategies.scala:85)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:288)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveTranslationLayerCheck.apply(HiveTranslationLayerStrategies.scala:85)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveTranslationLayerCheck.apply(HiveTranslationLayerStrategies.scala:83)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:87)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
>   at
>   scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
>   at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
>   at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:124)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:103)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:74)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)   ... 49
>   elided

do i need to add any properties in spark-submit  or shell ? or what is the alternate way to read this hiv e table using spark

hive table sample format:

```
  CREATE TABLE `hive``(                   |
|   `c_id` decimal(11,0),etc.........       
  ROW FORMAT SERDE                                   |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'      |
| WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (  
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                              |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'  |
| OUTPUTFORMAT                                       |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat' |
 LOCATION                                           |
|  path= 'hdfs://gjuyada/bbts/scl/raw' |
| TBLPROPERTIES (                                    |
|   'bucketing_version'='2',                         |
|   'spark.sql.create.version'='2.3.2.3.1.0.0-78',   |
|   'spark.sql.sources.provider'='orc',              |
|   'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts'='1',         |
|   'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0'='{"type":"struct","fields":
[{"name":"Czz_ID","type":"decimal(11,0)","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},
{"name":"DzzzC_CD","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},
{"name":"C0000_S_N","type":"decimal(11,0)","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},
{"name":"P_ _NB","type":"decimal(11,0)","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},
{"name":"C_YYYY","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},"type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"Cv_ID","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},
|   'transactional'='true',                          |
|   'transient_lastDdlTime'='1574817059')
```

Comment: share the hive table information that you are trying to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you are trying to reading **`Transactional table`**`(transactional = true)` into Spark.

> Officially **`Spark`** not yet supported for **Hive-ACID** table, get a
> **`full dump/incremental dump of acid table`** to regular **`hive orc/parquet`** partitioned table then read the data using spark.

There is a Open Jira [SPARK-15348](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15348) to add support for reading **`Hive ACID`** table.

- If you run **`major compaction`** on Acid table(from hive) then spark able to read **`base_XXX`** directories only but not delta directories [SPARK-16996](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16996) addressed in this jira.
- There are some workaround to read acid tables using [SPARK-LLAP](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/156816/hive-transactional-tables-are-not-readable-by-spar.html) as mentioned in this link.
- **I think** starting from **`HDP-3.X`** [HiveWareHouseConnector](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/integrating-hive/content/hive_hivewarehouseconnector_for_handling_apache_spark_data.html) is able to support to read HiveAcid tables.
- You can create an `snapshot` of the transactional table as **`non transactional`** and then read the data from the table.

  ```
   **`create table <non_trans> stored as orc as select * from <transactional_table>`**
  ```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

1.Create an external hive table:

```
 CREATE external TABLE `<ext_tab_name>`(  
       <col_name>       <data_type>....etc
           )
    stored as orc
    location '<path>';
```

2.Then overwrite to the above external table with existing transactional table data.

```
 insert overwrite table <ext_tab_name> select * from <transactional_tab_name>;
```

Comment: could you give some info related to creating snapshot of non-transnational table from transnational ,do i need to mention transnational=false while creating hive table from transnational ?

Comment: @user12763124, no need i think, if ur using `HDP-3` then make sure the snapshot table is not transactional enabled!, **(or)** you can `create an external table` with `same schema as transactional table` then **insert overwrite to external table** by *selecting data from transactional table*!!

Comment: **create table <non_trans> stored as orc as select * from <transactional_table>**
is showing bucket out of range -1 error or  **create an external table with same schema as transactional table** is giving same  bucket out of range -1 error

Comment: yes it is transactional =true on the hive table that was intially created using spark

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207439/discussion-between-shu-and-user12763124).

Answer (score 2):

You need to create table with `TBLPROPERTIES ( 'transactional'='false' )`

```
CREATE TABLE your_table(
  `col` string, 
  `col2` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES ( 
  'transactional'='false' 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/qubole/spark-acid - Hive ACID Data Source for Apache Spark, which will allow you to read Hive ACID/transaction tables.

If you are using Cloudera, check out Hive Warehouse Connector (HWC), which is based on the qubole project:

- [HWC main page](https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/latest/integrating-hive-and-bi/topics/hive_hivewarehouseconnector_for_handling_apache_spark_data.html)
- If you can run the Spark app as a super user and you don't need authorization, use the faster Spark Direct Reader mode: [blog post](https://blog.cloudera.com/enabling-high-speed-spark-direct-reader-for-apache-hive-acid-tables/)